# MYSQL how i can ADD column that has comma separated name

Tags: php, mysql, sql

i want to add column inside table. column name is name,surname
how i can add this column inside already created table?
like alter table MyTable ADD name,surname Varchar(100)  ???

Comment: This sounds like an [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem). Why are you trying to cram two values into a single column?

Comment: I see no genuine reason to do this.

Comment: my columns name is (aaaa,bbb) i whant to add this as one column name

Comment: is it possible to ADD column that has comma separated name?

Comment: If you insist on making everything more cumbersome: weird column names just need to be wrapped in backticks. (Again / future users: *don't do this*. Just a literal answer to the question title.)

Comment: This idea is beyond terrible. Don't do it.

Comment: im not asking if its bad or good idea i asked only if is it possible

Answer (score 4):

Add two separate columns:

```
alter table mytable add name varchar(100);
alter table mytable add surname varchar(100);
```

Simply concatenate the values together if you want them in a list:

```
select concat_ws(', ', surname, name) as surname_name
```

Don't combine them into a single column.

Comment: my columns name is aaaaa,bbbbb its coma separated

Comment: @RezoKobaidze . . . Break it up at the application layer.  It contains two separate elements.  Each should have its own column (or row).

Comment: i know but is it possible to ADD column that has comma separated name???

Comment: @RezoKobaidze . . . You can use backticks.  They are the escape character in MySQL.  But don't do it!  If you want two parts to a name, separate them with an underscore:  `name_surname`.  That makes it much easier to query in the future.

Answer (score 0):

```sql
ALTER TABLE tablename ADD COLUMN `name,age` VARCHAR(45) NULL DEFAULT NULL;
```

Name, age has to be between negation symbols.
I type it here but it is not showing up on UI after I post it.
Here ` is the one above tab on keyboard.

Anything inside those negation symbols is considered as a column name.

Comment: thanks a lot it helped example:

Comment: that sign helped